# Potty training my 22-month-old son

Tags: toddler, potty-training

We are currently on day 3 of potty training, my son who is 22 months old is showing all the signs, our accidents seem to happen when playing, he only let's out a small amount and the does the rest on the potty! (Rain drop)

Should we continue? Or shelve it for a few weeks?

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! Did you check the other questions and answers on potty training here? I have a hunch that you might find what you looking for somewhere here: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/potty-training

Comment: So, basically, everything seems fine, and you wonder if you should continue? Or did I miss something?

Comment: I read it as he is having small accidents, and she is wondering how/if to proceed. Unsure, actually.

Comment: Potty training can be a long process. It takes consistency and patience from the parents. Search around for some tips and techniques that fit into your lifestyle. Keep at it!

Comment: Keep on going. My daughter has been potty trained for over a year now but I still remind her to go to the bathroom. I don't know if reminding her is necessary, but I do it anyhow and probably will for a couple years. Do you ask your son if he needs to go? Or possibly rally him to the bathroom every 3 or 4 hours to have him go? Kids have a strange ability to conjure the need if you place them on a toilet.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say keep going.  Don't overreact (or react at all really) to the little accidents.  Just be encouraging when he gets on the potty.  Biggest thing is don't stress.  Kids do it at different ages, but it will happen for all of them sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

Don't stop now. From what you've said, he's about "90 percent" there. Just be patient, keep at it, and the remaining 10 per cent will come.